# Microsoft Sharepoint CSOM error - Default constructor not found for type Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentTypeId

Tags: c#, android, .net, unity-game-engine, sharepoint

Looking for advice if I have missed something obvious here please.
I suspect it is related to reference assemblies.

I use Unity 3D for an Android App that communicates with SharePoint Online.

After upgrading from Unity 2022.3.2f1 to 2023.2.10f1 I get the error:
Default constructor not found for type Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentTypeId

The error occurs when attempting to read a SharePoint list.

The error only shows in Android Logcat when built to the device (runtime).

```
2024/02/22 14:18:19.515 21552 21581 Error Unity MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentTypeId
2024/02/22 14:18:19.515 21552 21581 Error Unity   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
2024/02/22 14:18:19.515 21552 21581 Error Unity   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ScriptTypeMap.CreateObjectFromScriptType (System.String scriptType, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext context) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
2024/02/22 14:18:19.515 21552 21581 Error Unity   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.JsonReader.ReadJsonObject (System.Type fallbackType) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
2024/02/22 14:18:19.515 21552 21581 Error Unity   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.JsonReader.ReadKeyValue () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
2024/02/22 14:18:19.515 21552 21581 Error Unity   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem.InitNonPropertyFieldFromJson (System.String peekedName, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.JsonReader reader) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
2024/02/22 14:18:19.515 21552 21581 Error Unity   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject.FromJson (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.JsonReader reader) [0x00000]
```

The project has imported and upgraded successfully (as far as i can tell)
It runs completely fine in the Unity Editor on windows.
The error only occurs when it is 'built' to an Android device.

The other SharePoint functions, such as upload/download a file, get a directory list of online folders or writing to a SharePoint list all work.
The only issue is when trying to read a SharePoint list.
All this code has worked previously for over a year and still works on the 'old' build.

```
  public static void ReadListItem(string site, string listName, string camlViewXml)
        {

                clientContext = GetNewClientContext(site);
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List myList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = camlViewXml;
              tempListColl = myList.GetItems(camlQuery);


            clientContext.Load(tempListColl);

                try
                {
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    Debug.Log("List Update stopped:" + ex.Message);

                }
                catch (ServerException ex) { Debug.Log("List Update stopped:" + ex.Message); return; }

        }
```

The error also occurs if called from an asynchronous Task too.

This code works fine on the old version of Unity with .Net Standard 2.0
The code works fine and runs in the Unity Editor itself.

On the new one (which only allows .net Standard 2.1), it creates the error when built and running on a device.
I believe it is something to do with the .dll references and dependencies and that some have an issue with Standard 2.1
I can't see any mention of the error anywhere else. As far as i can tell from Microsoft documentation, the function should still work in the CSOM library.
The error occurs when trying to simply get a SharePoint list item, which is the first step really.

I have used Nuget to update the packages, and the issue persists. Unless i have done something wrong here?